# Syncing ethereum with get from my another node without execution and verifying txs

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I have 2 ethereum full synced geth node but i need one more geth full node.
however ethereum geth syncing is very slow because verifying the downloaded syncing datas.
Can I skip the verifying datas from my authorized nodes?

trusted node option is acted as just a static node

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest backing up your **chaindata folder** from one of your already synchronized nodes and restoring it on the third node:

1. Gracefully stop your already synced node (SIGINT/CTRL-C).
2. Tar compress the chaindata folder with zstd or lz4 compression.
3. Extract to chaindata folder (Replace it) at the location geth is saving the state.
4. It will then only sync from that point to head of the chain.